# managing the events in an array of radio buttons

Tags: vb6

This code below only works when the option1 is selected, i would like to know my errors and the logic behind
Goes thus;

```
    Dim Question(2) as string
    Dim i as long 
   Private Sub Form1_Load()
    Question(0)= "q1 here"
    Question(1)="q2 here"
    Question(2)="q3 here"
    For i = 0 to 2
    if option1(i).Value=True Then
    Label1.Caption=Option1(i).Caption 
    Else: Label1.caption= MsgBox "Please Select an Option"
    End IF
    Next i
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to tell what you are doing from the above code. However if all you want to do is display a question in a label when an OptionButton is clicked try below. If this doesn't answer your question please clarify.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load()

    Question(0).Caption = "q1 here"
    Question(1).Caption = "q2 here"
    Question(2).Caption = "q3 here"

End Sub

Private Sub Question_Click(Index As Integer)
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To 2
        If Question(i).Value = True Then
            Label1.Caption = Question(i).Caption
            Exit For
        Else
            Label1.Caption = "Please Select an Option"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```